# How can I assign different values to the input box from my color picker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have two different input box id and i have two different color picker palette. What I'm trying to do is let the user select a color and have selected color printed in the input box. At the moment it's half way working. Problem is when the user selects from color palettes two of the input boxes changes instead of the first or second one.

I would like to user select first color and its suppose to display on the first input box and when user selects the second color its suppose to display on the second input box.

```
    var selector = '.color-list .color';
    $(".color").css('background', function() {
      return $(this).data('color');
    });

    $(selector).on('click', function() {
      var colorName = $(this).data('name');
      var colorHEX = $(this).data('color');
      $(selector).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('');
      $('#options_1010_text').val(colorName);
      $('#test-bg').css('background-color', colorHEX);

    });



    var selector = '.color-list .color';
    $(".color").css('background', function() {
      return $(this).data('color');
    });

    $(selector).on('click', function() {
      var colorName = $(this).data('name');
      var colorHEX = $(this).data('color');
      $(selector).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('');
      $('#options_1011_text').val(colorName);
      $('#test-bg').css('background-color', colorHEX);

    });

    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("customAccordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var jobCount = $('#list1 .in1').length - 1;
      $('.list-count1').text(jobCount + ' items');


      $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
        //$(this).addClass('hidden');

        var searchTerm = $("#search-text").val();
        var listItem = $('#list1').children('li');


        var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

        //extends :contains to be case insensitive
        $.extend($.expr[':'], {
          'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array) {
            return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
              .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
          }
        });


        $("#list1 .color-list li").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
          $(this).addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in1');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.out').addClass('hidden');
          }, 300);
        });

        $("#list1 li:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
          $(this).removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in1');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.in1').removeClass('hiding');
          }, 1);
        });


        var jobCount = $('#list1 .in1').length - 1;
        $('.list-count1').text(jobCount + ' items');

        //shows empty state text when no jobs found
        if (jobCount == '0') {
          $('#list1').addClass('empty');
        } else {
          $('#list1').removeClass('empty');
        }

      });
    });




    $(document).ready(function() {

      var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length - 1;
      $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');


      $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
        //$(this).addClass('hidden');

        var searchTerm = $("#search-text").val();
        var listItem = $('#list2').children('li');


        var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

        //extends :contains to be case insensitive
        $.extend($.expr[':'], {
          'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array) {
            return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
              .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
          }
        });


        $("#list2 .color-list li").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
          $(this).addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in2');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.out').addClass('hidden');
          }, 300);
        });

        $("#list2 li:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
          $(this).removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in2');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.in2').removeClass('hiding');
          }, 1);
        });


        var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length - 1;
        $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');

        //shows empty state text when no jobs found
        if (jobCount == '0') {
          $('#list2').addClass('empty');
        } else {
          $('#list2').removeClass('empty');
        }

      });
    });
    .customAccordion {
      color: #f4f4f4;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      outline: none;
      transition: 0.5s;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .active,
    .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .panel {
      padding: 0 0px;
      background-color: #fff;
      max-height: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      border: none;
      box-shadow: rgb(33 35 38 / 50%) 0px 10px 10px -10px;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .colPadding {
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .chartTitle,
    .chartTitle:hover {
      color: #f4f4f4;
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .chartViewAll,
    .chartViewAll:hover {
      color: #f4f4f4 !important;
      font-size: 12px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .yellowHues,
    .yellowHues:active {
      background-color: #d7b327 !important;
    }

    .orangeHues,
    .orangeHues:active {
      background-color: #ff7700 !important;
    }

    .redHues,
    .redHues:active {
      background-color: #d64818 !important;
    }

    .violetHues,
    .violetHues:active {
      background-color: #8b1892 !important;
    }

    .blueHues,
    .blueHues:active {
      background-color: #0d2791 !important;
    }

    .greenHues,
    .greenHues:active {
      background-color: #1e7f16 !important;
    }

    .greyHues,
    .greyHues:active {
      background-color: #888888 !important;
    }

    .brownHues,
    .brownHues:active {
      background-color: #6c4a11 !important;
    }

    .whiteAndBlackHues,
    .whiteAndBlackHues:active {
      background-color: #000000 !important;
    }

    .chartIcon {
      fill: #f4f4f4;
      height: 20px;
    }

    .block-center {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .color-picker {
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 0px;
      padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
    }

    .color-list {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .color-list li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-right: 30px;
      margin-left: 30px;
    }

    .color {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      background-color: attr(data-color);
      transition: transform 0.3s;
    }

    .color:not(.active):hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .form-control {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #D7D1D5;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      padding: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.75;
    }

    .ralChartAccordionDiv {
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .colorPickerCol {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .ral-chart-form {
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    .color:not(.active) p {
      cursor: pointer;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    .color:not(.active):hover p {
      cursor: pointer;
      visibility: visible;
    }

    #search-text {
      border-radius: 50px;
      border-color: #2b2b2b;
      color: #2b2b2b;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
    }

     ::placeholder {
      color: #2b2b2b;
      opacity: 1;
      /* Firefox */
    }

     :-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
      color: #2b2b2b;
    }

     ::-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Microsoft Edge */
      color: #2b2b2b;
    }

    svg.bi.bi-search {
      fill: #2b2b2b;
      height: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -55px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 428px) {
      svg.bi.bi-search {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    .hidden {
      display: none !important;
    }
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="list1">
      <li class="in1">


        <div class="customAccordion yellowHues">
          <p class="chartTitle">Yellow Hues</p>
          <p class="chartViewAll">View All -
            <span class="list-count1"></span>
            <svg class="chartIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" class="bi bi-arrow-down-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                          <path
                                                d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                                    </svg>
          </p>
        </div>


        <div class="panel">

          <div class="color-picker block-center">
            <ul class="color-list">

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#cdba88" data-name="RAL 1000">
                <p class="ral-1000">RAL 1000</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#d0b084" data-name="RAL 1001">
                <p class="ral-1001">RAL 1001</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#d2aa6d" data-name="RAL 1002">
                <p class="ral-1002">RAL 1002</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#f9a800" data-name="RAL 1003">
                <p class="ral-1003">RAL 1003</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#e49e00" data-name="RAL 1004">
                <p class="ral-1004">RAL 1004</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#cb8e00" data-name="RAL 1005">
                <p class="ral-1005">RAL 1005</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#e29000" data-name="RAL 1006">
                <p class="ral-1006">RAL 1006</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#e88c00" data-name="RAL 1007">
                <p class="ral-1007">RAL 1007</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#af804f" data-name="RAL 1011">
                <p class="ral-1011">RAL 1011</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#ddaf27" data-name="RAL 1012">
                <p class="ral-1012">RAL 1012</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#e3d9c6" data-name="RAL 1013">
                <p class="ral-1013">RAL 1013</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#ddc49a" data-name="RAL 1014">
                <p class="ral-1014">RAL 1014</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#e6d2b5" data-name="RAL 1015">
                <p class="ral-1015">RAL 1015</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#f1dd38" data-name="RAL 1016">
                <p class="ral-1016">RAL 1016</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#f6a950" data-name="RAL 1017">
                <p class="ral-1017">RAL 1017</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#faca30" data-name="RAL 1018">
                <p class="ral-1018">RAL 1018</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#a48f7a" data-name="RAL 1019">
                <p class="ral-1019">RAL 1019</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#a08f65" data-name="RAL 1020">
                <p class="ral-1020">RAL 1020</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#f6b600" data-name="RAL 1021">
                <p class="ral-1021">RAL 1021</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#f7b500" data-name="RAL 1023">
                <p class="ral-1023">RAL 1023</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#ba8f4c" data-name="RAL 1024">
                <p class="ral-1024">RAL 1024</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#ffff00" data-name="RAL 1026">
                <p class="ral-1026">RAL 1026</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#a77f0e" data-name="RAL 1027">
                <p class="ral-1027">RAL 1027</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#ff9b00" data-name="RAL 1028">
                <p class="ral-1028">RAL 1028</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#e2a300" data-name="RAL 1032">
                <p class="ral-1032">RAL 1032</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#f99a1c" data-name="RAL 1033">
                <p class="ral-1033">RAL 1033</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#eb9c52" data-name="RAL 1034">
                <p class="ral-1034">RAL 1034</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#908370" data-name="RAL 1035">
                <p class="ral-1035">RAL 1035</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#80643f" data-name="RAL 1036">
                <p class="ral-1036">RAL 1036</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in1" data-color="#f09200" data-name="RAL 1037">
                <p class="ral-1037">RAL 1037</p>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>



      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="colPadding"></div>



    <ul id="list2">
      <li class="in2">


        <div class="customAccordion orangeHues">
          <p class="chartTitle">Orange Hues</p>
          <p class="chartViewAll">View All -
            <span class="list-count2"></span>
            <svg class="chartIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" class="bi bi-arrow-down-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                      <path
                                            d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                                </svg>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="panel">

          <div class="color-picker block-center">
            <ul class="color-list">

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#EEA205" data-name="RAL 2000">
                <p class="ral-2000">RAL 2000</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#DD7907" data-name="RAL 2001">
                <p class="ral-2001">RAL 2001</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#BE4E20" data-name="RAL 2002">
                <p class="ral-2002">RAL 2002</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#C63927" data-name="RAL 2003">
                <p class="ral-2003">RAL 2003</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#FA842B" data-name="RAL 2004">
                <p class="ral-2004">RAL 2004</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#E75B12" data-name="RAL 2005">
                <p class="ral-2005">RAL 2005</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#FF2300" data-name="RAL 2007">
                <p class="ral-2007">RAL 2007</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#FFA421" data-name="RAL 2008">
                <p class="ral-2008">RAL 2008</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#F3752C" data-name="RAL 2009">
                <p class="ral-2009">RAL 2009</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#E15501" data-name="RAL 2010">
                <p class="ral-2010">RAL 2010</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#D4652F" data-name="RAL 2011">
                <p class="ral-2011">RAL 2011</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#EC7C25" data-name="RAL 2012">
                <p class="ral-2012">RAL 2012</p>
              </li>

              <li class="color in2" data-color="#DB6A50" data-name="RAL 2013">
                <p class="ral-2013">RAL 2013</p>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>




      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="colPadding"></div>


    <input id="options_1010_text">
    <input id="options_1011_text">






    <div class="customAccordion orangeHues">
                          <p class="chartTitle">Orange Hues</p>
                          <p class="chartViewAll">View All - 
                                <span class="list-count2"></span>
                                <svg class="chartIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                      class="bi bi-arrow-down-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                      <path
                                            d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                                </svg>
                          </p>
                    </div>
    
    <div class="panel">
    
          <div class="color-picker block-center">
                <ul class="color-list">
    
                      <li class="color in2" data-color="#EEA205" data-name="RAL 2000">
                        <p class="ral-2000">RAL 2000</p>
                      </li>
                  
                      <li class="color in2" data-color="#DD7907" data-name="RAL 2001">
                        <p class="ral-2001">RAL 2001</p>
                      </li>
                  
                </ul>
    
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="customAccordion yellowHues">
                              <p class="chartTitle">Yellow Hues</p>
                              <p class="chartViewAll">View All - 
                                    <span class="list-count1"></span>
                                    <svg class="chartIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                          class="bi bi-arrow-down-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                          <path
                                                d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                                    </svg>
                              </p>
                        </div>
        
        
        <div class="panel">
        
              <div class="color-picker block-center">
                    <ul class="color-list">
        
                          <li class="color in1" data-color="#cdba88" data-name="RAL 1000">
                            <p class="ral-1000">RAL 1000</p>
                          </li>
                      
                          <li class="color in1" data-color="#d0b084" data-name="RAL 1001">
                            <p class="ral-1001">RAL 1001</p>
                          </li>
                      
                        
                    </ul>
        
              </div>
        </div>
    







   

     <script>
        var selector = '.color-list .color';
        $(".color").css('background', function () { 
            return $(this).data('color');
        });
        
        $(selector).on('click', function(){
          var colorName = $(this).data('name');
          var colorHEX = $(this).data('color');
          $(selector).removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('');
          $('#options_1010_text').val(colorName);
          $('#test-bg').css('background-color',colorHEX);
          
        });
        </script>
        
        
          <script>
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("customAccordion");
            var i;
            
            for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
              acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                } 
              });
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Now you've removed the snippet demo altogether. That makes it less convenient for others to help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a million ways to do this. One would be to store an input ID value somewhere. I've put it on the closest list element. You could also target inputs by index, referring to the list index, if you didn't want to hard-code IDs.

I also tweaked your CSS to fix the horizontal overrun.

```js
var selector = '.color-list .color';

$(".color").css('background', function() {
  return $(this).data('color');
});

$(selector).on('click', function() {
  var colorName = $(this).data('name');
  var colorHEX = $(this).data('color');
  $(selector).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('');
  $($(this).closest('ul').data('input')).val(colorName);
  $('#test-bg').css('background-color', colorHEX);
});

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("customAccordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var jobCount = $('#list1 .in1').length - 1;
  $('.list-count1').text(jobCount + ' items');

  $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    //$(this).addClass('hidden');

    var searchTerm = $("#search-text").val();
    var listItem = $('#list1').children('li');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

    //extends :contains to be case insensitive
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
      'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
          .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }
    });

    $("#list1 .color-list li").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in1');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.out').addClass('hidden');
      }, 300);
    });

    $("#list1 li:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in1');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.in1').removeClass('hiding');
      }, 1);
    });

    var jobCount = $('#list1 .in1').length - 1;
    $('.list-count1').text(jobCount + ' items');

    //shows empty state text when no jobs found
    if (jobCount == '0') {
      $('#list1').addClass('empty');
    } else {
      $('#list1').removeClass('empty');
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length - 1;
  $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');

  $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    //$(this).addClass('hidden');

    var searchTerm = $("#search-text").val();
    var listItem = $('#list2').children('li');


    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

    //extends :contains to be case insensitive
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
      'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
          .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }
    });

    $("#list2 .color-list li").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in2');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.out').addClass('hidden');
      }, 300);
    });

    $("#list2 li:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in2');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.in2').removeClass('hiding');
      }, 1);
    });

    var jobCount = $('#list2 .in2').length - 1;
    $('.list-count2').text(jobCount + ' items');

    //shows empty state text when no jobs found
    if (jobCount == '0') {
      $('#list2').addClass('empty');
    } else {
      $('#list2').removeClass('empty');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.picker-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.customAccordion {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* width: 100%; */
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: rgb(33 35 38 / 50%) 0px 10px 10px -10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.colPadding {
  padding: 20px;
}

.chartTitle,
.chartTitle:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.chartViewAll,
.chartViewAll:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4 !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.yellowHues,
.yellowHues:active {
  background-color: #d7b327 !important;
}

.orangeHues,
.orangeHues:active {
  background-color: #ff7700 !important;
}

.redHues,
.redHues:active {
  background-color: #d64818 !important;
}

.violetHues,
.violetHues:active {
  background-color: #8b1892 !important;
}

.blueHues,
.blueHues:active {
  background-color: #0d2791 !important;
}

.greenHues,
.greenHues:active {
  background-color: #1e7f16 !important;
}

.greyHues,
.greyHues:active {
  background-color: #888888 !important;
}

.brownHues,
.brownHues:active {
  background-color: #6c4a11 !important;
}

.whiteAndBlackHues,
.whiteAndBlackHues:active {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
}

.chartIcon {
  fill: #f4f4f4;
  height: 20px;
}

.block-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.color-picker {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
}

.color-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.color-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.color {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: attr(data-color);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.color:not(.active):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D7D1D5;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

.ralChartAccordionDiv {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.colorPickerCol {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ral-chart-form {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.color:not(.active) p {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.color:not(.active):hover p {
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}

#search-text {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #2b2b2b;
}

 ::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #2b2b2b;
}

svg.bi.bi-search {
  fill: #2b2b2b;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -55px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 428px) {
  svg.bi.bi-search {
    display: none;
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list1" class="picker-list">
  <li class="in1">
    <div class="customAccordion yellowHues">
      <p class="chartTitle">Yellow Hues</p>
      <p class="chartViewAll">View All -
        <span class="list-count1"></span>
        <svg class="chartIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" class="bi bi-arrow-down-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path
                    d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
        </svg>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="color-picker block-center">
        <ul class="color-list" data-input="#options_1010_text">
          <li class="color in1" data-color="#cdba88" data-name="RAL 1000">
            <p class="ral-1000">RAL 1000</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#d0b084" data-name="RAL 1001">
            <p class="ral-1001">RAL 1001</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#d2aa6d" data-name="RAL 1002">
            <p class="ral-1002">RAL 1002</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#f9a800" data-name="RAL 1003">
            <p class="ral-1003">RAL 1003</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#e49e00" data-name="RAL 1004">
            <p class="ral-1004">RAL 1004</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#cb8e00" data-name="RAL 1005">
            <p class="ral-1005">RAL 1005</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#e29000" data-name="RAL 1006">
            <p class="ral-1006">RAL 1006</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#e88c00" data-name="RAL 1007">
            <p class="ral-1007">RAL 1007</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#af804f" data-name="RAL 1011">
            <p class="ral-1011">RAL 1011</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#ddaf27" data-name="RAL 1012">
            <p class="ral-1012">RAL 1012</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#e3d9c6" data-name="RAL 1013">
            <p class="ral-1013">RAL 1013</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#ddc49a" data-name="RAL 1014">
            <p class="ral-1014">RAL 1014</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#e6d2b5" data-name="RAL 1015">
            <p class="ral-1015">RAL 1015</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#f1dd38" data-name="RAL 1016">
            <p class="ral-1016">RAL 1016</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#f6a950" data-name="RAL 1017">
            <p class="ral-1017">RAL 1017</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#faca30" data-name="RAL 1018">
            <p class="ral-1018">RAL 1018</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#a48f7a" data-name="RAL 1019">
            <p class="ral-1019">RAL 1019</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#a08f65" data-name="RAL 1020">
            <p class="ral-1020">RAL 1020</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#f6b600" data-name="RAL 1021">
            <p class="ral-1021">RAL 1021</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#f7b500" data-name="RAL 1023">
            <p class="ral-1023">RAL 1023</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#ba8f4c" data-name="RAL 1024">
            <p class="ral-1024">RAL 1024</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#ffff00" data-name="RAL 1026">
            <p class="ral-1026">RAL 1026</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#a77f0e" data-name="RAL 1027">
            <p class="ral-1027">RAL 1027</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#ff9b00" data-name="RAL 1028">
            <p class="ral-1028">RAL 1028</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#e2a300" data-name="RAL 1032">
            <p class="ral-1032">RAL 1032</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#f99a1c" data-name="RAL 1033">
            <p class="ral-1033">RAL 1033</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#eb9c52" data-name="RAL 1034">
            <p class="ral-1034">RAL 1034</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#908370" data-name="RAL 1035">
            <p class="ral-1035">RAL 1035</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#80643f" data-name="RAL 1036">
            <p class="ral-1036">RAL 1036</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in1" data-color="#f09200" data-name="RAL 1037">
            <p class="ral-1037">RAL 1037</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="colPadding"></div>

<ul id="list2" class="picker-list">
  <li class="in2">
    <div class="customAccordion orangeHues">
      <p class="chartTitle">Orange Hues</p>
      <p class="chartViewAll">View All -
        <span class="list-count2"></span>
        <svg class="chartIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" class="bi bi-arrow-down-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path
                    d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 10.293V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
        </svg>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="color-picker block-center">
        <ul class="color-list" data-input="#options_1011_text">
          <li class="color in2" data-color="#EEA205" data-name="RAL 2000">
            <p class="ral-2000">RAL 2000</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#DD7907" data-name="RAL 2001">
            <p class="ral-2001">RAL 2001</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#BE4E20" data-name="RAL 2002">
            <p class="ral-2002">RAL 2002</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#C63927" data-name="RAL 2003">
            <p class="ral-2003">RAL 2003</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#FA842B" data-name="RAL 2004">
            <p class="ral-2004">RAL 2004</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#E75B12" data-name="RAL 2005">
            <p class="ral-2005">RAL 2005</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#FF2300" data-name="RAL 2007">
            <p class="ral-2007">RAL 2007</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#FFA421" data-name="RAL 2008">
            <p class="ral-2008">RAL 2008</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#F3752C" data-name="RAL 2009">
            <p class="ral-2009">RAL 2009</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#E15501" data-name="RAL 2010">
            <p class="ral-2010">RAL 2010</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#D4652F" data-name="RAL 2011">
            <p class="ral-2011">RAL 2011</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#EC7C25" data-name="RAL 2012">
            <p class="ral-2012">RAL 2012</p>
          </li>

          <li class="color in2" data-color="#DB6A50" data-name="RAL 2013">
            <p class="ral-2013">RAL 2013</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="colPadding"></div>

<input id="options_1010_text">
<input id="options_1011_text">
```